# trouble finding NullPointerException used try catch instead of if statement

Tags: java

I've been struggling to find why my `if` statement didnt work properly so I used a `try catch` block instead. This is the if statement as I had it:

```
//selectArtistByName returns an Artist object
if (!selectArtistByName(artist.getName()).equals(artist.getName()) || 
    selectArtistByName(artist.getName())==null) {
    //save data to database
}
```

When I ran the above, I got a `NullPointerException` because the method `selectArtistByName` was returning `null` as the database was empty. What I don't understand is why it didn't go in the `if` statement when I was getting `null`. So I did this and it worked:

```
try {
    if (!selectArtistByName(artist.getName()).equals(artist.getName())) {
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    m_db.insert(TABLE_ARTIST, null, artistContents);
}
```

I'm not a Java guru but it looks like a horrible fix to me. How could I fix this.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to change the order of condition in `if` block:

```
if (selectArtistByName(artist.getName()) == null || 
   !selectArtistByName(artist.getName()).equals(artist.getName())) {
    //save data to database
}
```

- Do the `null` check first.
- If that succeeds, then 2<sup>nd</sup> condition is not evaluated, and hence no `NullPointerException`. This is how *short-circuit OR* operator works. It only evaluates the 2<sup>nd</sup> expression, if 1<sup>st</sup> one evaluates to *false*.
- If null check fails, then 2<sup>nd</sup> condition is evaluated, which wouldn't throw `NPE`, as it has already been confirmed by first condition.

Also, as rightly pointed out by @ruakh in comment, your condition seems to be broken. `selectArtistByName` sounds to be returning an *Artist*, which you can't compare with `String`.

I guess, you don't even need the 2<sup>nd</sup> condition. I would assume, `selectArtistByName()` method has already done the equality check for *name*, based on which it will return *Artist*. Just check that `selectArtistByName` method return `null`, that would be enough. So, you should change the `if` block to:

```
if (selectArtistByName(artist.getName()) == null) {
    //save data to database
}
```

Comment: +1, but it should be noted that there's another problem here: it's unlikely that `selectArtistByName(artist.getName()).equals(artist.getName())` will ever be true, since `selectArtistByName(artist.getName())` is an `Artist` and `artist.getName()` is presumably a `String`. (I'm not sure exactly what the condition is *supposed* to look like, though.)

Comment: @ruakh. Ah! Good catch. Added that to the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the null condition check at the beginning to shortcut when artist is unknown:

```
if (selectArtistByName(artist.getName())==null || !selectArtistByName(artist.getName()).equals(artist.getName())) {
     //save data to database
}
```

You can find more info about lazy evaluation in this other question: [Does Java have lazy evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189209/does-java-have-lazy-evaluation)