# null pointer exception depending on order of an or statement

Tags: java

This for loop is supposed to go through a String array and make the value hasEmpty true if the array contains either a null value or empty String. The following code gives me a NullPointerException.

```
String[] names = {null, "B", "C"};
    boolean hasEmpty = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
        if ((names[i].equals("")) || (names[i] == null))
            hasEmpty = true;
    }
```

But if I change the order of the OR statement in the if clause, the following code seems to work. Can someone tell me why this is so?

```
String[] names = {null, "B", "C"};
    boolean hasEmpty = false;
    for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
        if ((names[i] == null) || (names[i].equals("")))
            hasEmpty = true;
    }
```

Comment: See also: [Does Java have lazy evaluation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189209/does-java-have-lazy-evaluation)

Comment: Side note: avoid using .equals(""). Simply call isEmpty() instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance depends how many nulls and empty strings you have. Maybe that was the reason you choose check for empty string first because it happens more often. You can do this too but you should avoid null pointer exception too. There is simple trick to do this - rely on your code, not on data. If you simple change what is compared with what and use your constants then it will work fine. Your constants are not null since they do exist.

```
if (("".equals(names[i])) || (names[i] == null)){/* Handling empty or null strings */}
```

See the difference?

Answer (score 3):

Because `||` is a short-circuit operator. As soon as it finds an operand that is true, from left to right, it doesn't even evaluates the other ones (because `true or anything` is always true).

The same goes with &&: if the first operand is false, it does evaluates the other ones, because `false && anything` is always false.

Answer (score 0):

`||` is checking the first condition first , it faces a `null` ... calling `equals` on `null` throws `NullPointerException`

when you check for `null` first the first condition will evaluate to `true` so it will skip checking the 2nd one

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564410/difference-between-and) to understand the difference between single and double or/and as logical operators in java

Answer (score 0):

As it is expected.

If the first argument of an OR statement is true, it does not need to evaluate the other.

The same is true for an AND statement and a false value. If the first is false, no need to evaluate the second.

Answer (score 0):

Code in `if` statements are evaluated lazily, meaning that they can exit if they know that they're going to fail. The first one fails because you're calling `null.equals("")` which will throw an error. The second one succeeds because you're checking if `names[i]` is `null` and if so the loop is exited.

```
if ((names[i] == null ) ||
    (names[i].equals(""))) // Don't bother checking if names[i] is null


if ((names[i].equals("")) ||
    (names[i] == null)) // Check null only if names[i].equals("") is false
```

Inverting the `||` to an `&&` might have it more sense:

```
if (names[i] != null && !names.equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` method needs the string not be `null`, if the value is null, it is not an object anymore and you actually call null.equals.(someOtherObject), then it throws `NullPointerException` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] names = {null, "B", "C"};

boolean hasEmpty = false;

for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++){
       /* change here */
        if (("".equals(names[i])) || (names[i] == null))
            hasEmpty = true;
    }
```

**Reason :**
You are trying to compare **null** value with **empty** string so in first code snippet you are getting NullPointerException. But in second code you changed that place of both conditions. The evaluation of OR condition is done as follow:

if first condition is fulfilled then only next part is checked.

means **if (a || b)**

if a is true then b will not be evaluated.
but if a is false then b will be evaluated.