# Is Java lazy when passing parameters to a method?

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation, lazy-initialization, short-circuiting

I am using this code:

```
A a = aMap.contains(key) ? aMap.get(key) : createAExpensively(key);
```

I believe that Java is lazy so if `aMap.contains(key))` then the `createAExpensively()` function is never called.

Then, I stumbled onto the `Map.getOrDefault()` method. If we instead use:

```
A a = aMap.getOrDefault(key, createAExpensively(key));
```

is Java still lazy in calling the `createAExpensively()` function?

It seems that Java will first create the object `A` and pass it as a method parameter, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189209/does-java-have-lazy-evaluation/26075774#26075774), but I'm not totally sure.

If Java is not lazy when using `Map.getOrDefault()`, what is the point of that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Java still lazy in calling the `createAExpensively()` function?
>   [in `.getOrDefault(key, createAExpensively(key))`]

Function parameters are evaluated (from left to right) before actually calling the function. So `createAExpensively(key)` will be evaluated before calling `getOrDefault`. This behavior is also known as [applicative order evaluation strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order).

> If Java is not lazy when using `Map.getOrDefault()`, what is the point of that method?

It's useful when the default value is not expensive to create,
for example when it's an already computed value or constant.
In that case the `Map.getOrDefault(...)` call allows a more compact syntax than the ternary operator.

If the default value is expensive to compute,
*and if you actually want to put the computed value in the map*,
then as of Java 8,
you can use [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
A a = aMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> createAExpensively(k));
```

Comment: `computeIfAbsent` is not the lazy version of `getOrDefault`. The former mutates the map if the key doesn't exist; the latter doesn't.

Comment: @HelderPereira Ouch, good call. Thanks, clarified that point.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't a method for it in the `Map` interface. However, we can still work it around with a single call to the map by using `Optional`s: `A a = Optional.ofNullable(aMap.get(key)).orElseGet(() -> createAExpensively(key));`.

Comment: @HelderPereira yeah, but I don't think it would be an improvement over the ternary.

Comment: Depends how expensive the calls to the map are. I have a map backed by RocksDB. :D

Answer (score 2):

Java is not lazy at all. You are using conditional operator to check whether `aMap.contains(key)`. If this is true it will never call `createAExpensively(key)` but `aMap.get(key)`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't lazy in that case.

The point of the method is that there's lots of times when the default is a constant or something you've already computed anyway.  For example, you might use `getOrDefault(key, 0)` when you're getting some kind of count and absent keys should be counted as zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

This is called ["short-circuit evaluation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) rather than lazy evaluation: The JVM is not *deferring* evaluation of `createExpensively()`, but rather *avoiding* it completely if it's not necessary, i.e if the condition holds.

See also the answer to the following question here on StackOverflow:

[Java logical operator short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759868/java-logical-operator-short-circuiting)

Answer (score 1):

It is not lazy at all.

This code

`A a = aMap.contains(key) ? aMap.get(key) : createAExpensively(key);`

evaulates to

```
if (aMap.contains(key)) 
{
  a = aMap.get(key);
}
else 
{
  a = createAExpensively(key);
}
```